# Setting the name of an object in an object array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, object

I have a 2 dimensional array of 5 columns and 5 rows, 25 cells in total. The user enters their name and selects what row and column. The row and column values are used to determine the index in the array of objects. I am unsure how to set the name to the particular object in the array. I have a seat class with a name attribute so I want to use the name to name the object in the object array.
I have tried to set the name using this:

```
bookings[row - 1, col - 1].setName(name);
```

My seat class:

```
namespace Movie
{
     class Seat
    {
        private String name;
        private Boolean booked;
        public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }


        public void book(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Boolean isBooked()
        {
            return booked;
        }
        public Seat(string nameIn)
        {
            name = nameIn;
        }

        public Seat() {
            name = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of your `seat` class. I guess what you want is `bookings[row - 1, col - 1].Name = "foo";` but I cannot tell without seeing the code

Comment: Please do not explain and clarify your question here in the comments. Instead, **edit** and improve the question itself (paying attention to nice formatting would be nice ;-) ).

Comment: FYI: Unless you want to use property change notifications, or letting the property getter or setter do some other/more stuff than just setting the backing field, you could simply use so-called [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties): `public string Name { get; set; }` Similarly, you can make IsBooked an auto-property, too, like `public bool IsBooked {get; private set;}`. Note the private setter, which only permits the `Seat` object itself to change the value of this property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are coming from Java-world where fields are accessed by "get" and "set" methods. In C# this is not common.

You can access the property as follows:

```
bookings[row - 1, col - 1].Name = "new name";
```